# Why I'm having the error ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, plugins, jquery-animate

I'm trying to import a custom jQuery plugin and apply it on a mouse move event via javascript. But I'm having an error ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function.
I'm interested what am I doinng wrong ? Maybe importing the wrong instance ?

```js
//jquery.move-animate.js
$.fn.moveAnimate = function () {
  return $(".move").animate(
    {
      position: "absolute",
      left: "150px"
    },
    1000
  );
};
// index.html
<div id="app">
  <h1 class="hello">hello</h1>
  <h1 class="move">move</h1>
</div>


//index.js
import $ from "jquery";
import moveAnimate from "./jquery.move-animate.js";

$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".hello").on("mousemove", moveAnimate);
});
```

Comment: I can't tell you why you're getting that specific error, as when I recreate your issue I don't see that. However there are several other problems with the code. Firstly, you've defined the function as `$.fn.moveAnimate ` so it needs to be invoked against a jQuery object not directly. I would suggest you defined it as `$.moveAnimate()` so that you can use it statically on a jQuery object. Also you're using `mousemove`, which will execute ***every single time the mouse moves*** in the target element. As the animation can only possibly run once, this is a complete waste....

Comment: ... I would suggest you change this to `mouseenter`. Lastly, you need to set the `.move` element to `position: absolute` when the page loads, not when the animation starts otherwise the element won't move. With those issues fixed, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/c4dphjtL/. If it's still not working for you after these changes, then I would suggest you check the version of jQuery you're using. Make sure it's 3.x or higher, and *not* the 'slim' branch.