# How can I change the position element via jQuery plugin on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, parameters

I need to change the position element via jQuery plugin on mousemove. I'm getting the mousemove coordinates in the index.js file and trying to pass it as params to jQuery custom plugin. So the indexjs variables are changed on mousemove, but when those are passed as params to plugin file, they are not being changed dynamically. Also having the error TypeError: ((S.event.special[o.origType] || {}).handle || o.handler).apply is not a function

```js
// Plugin jQuery file
(function ($) {
  $.fn.moveAnimate = function (posX,posY) {
    console.log('inner posX', posX)    // the posX is instantly === 1, not being changed reactively
    return $(this).each(function () {
      var $moveElement = $('.move');
      $moveElement.animate(
        {
          position: "absolute",
          left: `${posX} + "150px"`,
          top: `${posY} + "150px"`
        },
        1000
      );
    });
  };
})(jQuery);


// index.js file
$(function() {
  let globalX = 1
  let globalY = 1

    $("body").on("mousemove", (e) => {
      console.log('inner', globalX)  // changes the globalX
      globalX = e.pageX;
      globalY = e.pageY;
    })

    $("body").on("mousemove", $(".move").moveAnimate(globalX, globalY))
    
});
```

Comment: How is `moveAnimate()` defined? I assume from the use of the jQuery object instance, that it's a jQuery plugin, so it will not work being called directly. Your code is also using `posX` and `posY` out of scope, and you're executing the `moveAnimate()` function and passing its *return* value as the event handler for `mousemove`. You need to wrap that call in an anonymous function instead.

Comment: I assume in fact, that this follows on from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77379669/519413), but it seems this is an X/Y question where you're asking about a flawed attempt at a solution instead of describing the actual problem you're trying to solve. If you gave us that information, then we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the question trying to describe the initial question in details, can you please look at it?

Comment: Thanks for editing, I've added an answer for you. The 'TypeError' you're seeing seems to be unrelated to any of the code you've shown in the question

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues in your code.

- `` left: `${posX} + "150px"`, `` is not a valid mathematical operation. You need to add the integer values, then append `px` to the end: `left: (posX + 150) + 'px'`
- You only need *one* `body.mousemove` event handler.
- You need to invoke `$.fn.moveAnimate()` within the event handler, not executing it separately and providing its return value as the event handler.
- You don't need an `each()` loop in the `moveAnimate()` function, as you can apply `animate()` on a collection.
- Use the `mouseenter` event, not `mousemove`, as the latter will execute for *every* pixel the mouse moves, which is not what is required in this use case
- The `.move` element needs to be set as `position: absolute` ***before*** the animation runs in order for it to work. This can be done in CSS.

With those changes made, the code works fine:

```js
// Plugin jQuery file
(function($) {
  $.fn.moveAnimate = function(posX, posY) {
    return $(this).animate({
      left: (posX + 150) + 'px',
      top: (posY + 150) + 'px'
    }, 1000);
  };
})(jQuery);


// index.js file
$(function() {
  $("body").on("mouseenter", e => {
    globalX = e.pageX;
    globalY = e.pageY;
    $(".move").moveAnimate(globalX, globalY);
  });
});
```

```css
.move {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1 class="hello">hello</h1>
  <h1 class="move">move</h1>
</div>
```